# CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.JobModel>' to 'Models.JobModel'

Tags: c#, arrays, json, type-conversion, json-deserialization

I'm trying to request json object from a database through api. But the returned result was jsonArray. So I am trying to convert the jsonArray to json object to print to the user.

I have tried two different methods but it's giving me error.

Method 1:

```
public static async Task<JobModel> LoadJobIndex1(string specificValue)//Posting Type
    {
        string url = $"https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/kpav-sd4t.json?$limit=1&posting_type={ specificValue }";

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var client = new WebClient();
                var result = client.DownloadString("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/kpav-sd4t.json?$limit=1&level=1");

                JobResultModel results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobResultModel>(result);

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

Method 2:

```
public static async Task<JobModel> LoadJobIndex2(string specificValue)//Job Difficulty
{
    string url = $"https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/kpav-sd4t.json?$limit=3&level={ specificValue }";

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            JobResultModel result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JobResultModel>();

            return result.Results;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a model to store the response.

```
public class JobResultModel
{
    public List<JobModel> Results { get; set; }
}

public class JobModel
{
    public string Business_title { get; set; }//Name of the job
    public string Posting_type { get; set; }//Internal/External
    public string Level { get; set; }//Diffculty of the job
    public string Full_time_part_time_indicator { get; set; }
    public string Salary_range_from { get; set; }
    public string Salary_range_to { get; set; }
    public string Job_description { get; set; }
    public string Minimum_qual_requirements { get; set; }
    public string Preferred_skills { get; set; }
    public string To_apply { get; set; }
}
```

After that, I am trying to print the result to user.

```
var job = await GetJobDialog.LoadJobIndex1(specficValue);
                        await context.PostAsync($"Job Search Result : {Environment.NewLine}{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(job)}");
```

Here is a example of the result

```
[{

"business_title":"COLLEGE AIDE - CLERICAL",

"full_time_part_time_indicator":"P",

"job_description":"The Office of Collective Bargaining (OCB) is an independent, impartial governmental agency that resolves labor disputes between the City of New York and the City employeesâ€™ Unions.  OCB seeks a Clerical College Aide who will perform clerical and related work.    OCBâ€™s College Aide will attend to the officeâ€™s reception desk, answering and routing telephone calls and directing visitors to the proper destination.  He or she will also perform clerical work in relation to records, files, invoices and reports using alphabetical and numerical procedures including data/control coding.    He or she will perform clerical operations in an assigned area, such as the filing of material and the searching of files for material difficult to locate.    He or she will also prepare reports requiring the selection of data from simple records or statistics, and check records for accuracy of information and for conformity with established policy and procedures.",

"level":"1",

"minimum_qual_requirements":"For Assignment Level I:  Matriculation at an accredited college or graduate school. Employment is conditioned upon continuance as a student in a college or graduate school.  For Assignment Level II (Information Technology):  Matriculation at an accredited college or graduate school. Employment is conditioned upon continuance as a student in a college or graduate school with a specific course of study in information technology, computer science, management information systems, data processing, or closely related field, including or supplemented by 9 semester credits in an acceptable course of study.  For Assignment Level III (Information Technology Fellow):  Matriculation at an accredited college or graduate school. Employment is conditioned upon continuance as a student in a college or graduate school with a specific course of study in information technology, computer science, management information systems, data processing, or other area relevant to the information technology project(s) assigned, including or supplemented by 9 semester credits in an acceptable course of study. Appointments to this Assignment Level will be made by the Technology Steering Committee through the Department of Information Technology and Telecommunications.    SPECIAL NOTE  Maximum tenure for all Assignment Levels in the title of College Aide is 6 years. No student shall be employed more than half-time in any week in which classes in which the student is enrolled are in session. Students may be employed full-time during their vacation periods.",

"posting_type":"Internal",

"preferred_skills":"1.\tExcellent interpersonal communication skills  2.\tStrong work ethic and attention to detail  3.\tFamiliarity with Microsoft Office Suite","process_date":"2019-05-14T00:00:00.000","residency_requirement":"New York City residency is generally required within 90 days of appointment. However, City Employees in certain titles who have worked for the City for 2 continuous years may also be eligible to reside in Nassau, Suffolk, Putnam, Westchester, Rockland, or Orange County. To determine if the residency requirement applies to you, please discuss with the agency representative at the time of interview.",

"salary_range_from":"8.75",

"salary_range_to":"10.36","title_code_no":"10209",

"to_apply":"Click the â€œApply Nowâ€\u009d button.  While we appreciate every applicantâ€™s interest, only those under consideration will be contacted.  Do not email, mail or fax your resume to OCB directly.  No phone calls will be accepted."

}]
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: It is a really long error message. This is a chat bot im building, so i  have to put it into the bot framework emulator to test it. When it get to the json part, it response with a long error message.  Here is a link for the error message i copyed   [link](https://justpaste.it/edit/28500070/ad38fb4e74968d57)

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like you are trying to deserailize JSON to a single object but the JSON is actually represents the collection of objects. If you read the message carefully it also suggests how to resolve this error. Follow it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the JSON model is a collection itself, not an object with an internal collection called Results. To fix this you need to deserialise to a collection of JobModel.

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<JobModel>>();
```

Then you can just return the first item in the list

```
return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

OR, alter your method to return a list of JobModel and return the whole list

```
public static async Task<List<JobModel>> LoadJobIndex2(string specificValue)//Job Difficulty
```